# Order of mapping properties when loading from database

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0, mapping, instantiation, setter

Let's say I have this code:

```
public bool Important { get; set; }

private bool _dependsOnImportant;

public bool DependsOnImportant
{
    get;
    set 
    {
        if (value && !Important)
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
        _dependsOnImportant = value;

    }
}
```

I want to protect setting DependsOnImportant to true, so that it is only possible when Important is true. This is POCO class. According to: [Entity Framework 4.1 - Code first. Doesn't EF override my virtual members?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7007045/entity-framework-4-1-code-first-doesnt-ef-override-my-virtual-members) my setter will be used by EF when loading object from database.
How can I be sure that Important has already been set with data from database when DependsOnImportant setter is called? Will EF be smart enough to detect that one setter is using another and load that data first? I don't think so. I think a new object is created with default constructor (setting all fields to default values) and then setters are invoked to populate the object.

So my questions are: Can we determine the order in which setters are called? But most importantly: Do we want to have that knowledge?

Comment: In my humble opinion this type of setter is wrong even without EF. Properties look like plain data fields from consumer side and in your case the state of the object depends on the order you set the values to the properties. Some devepoper might simply swap the order of setting the property values and suddenly your application behaves differently or doesn't work anymore. I'd call that a side effect. It should be a method to make it explicit that logic depending on the current object state is inside (at least the setter should be a method, the getter could still exist as readonly property).

Comment: Thank very much for your for answer, much appreciated. I definitely see your point, but not completely  agree with it.
Without EF, the default value of Important on instantiation would be set to false (by default), it can also be also be explicitly set to false in constructor. The point of logic in the setter is to make sure Important is set to true, before DependsOnImportant is set to true. If another developer changes the order (which is wrong) my class will be safe and they will get an exception. But I can see it is not the slickest solution, that’s why I’m asking.
See other comment please

Comment: Assuming we take your road and provide an explicit setter method, how do I protect then the setter? I cannot make it private because EF would not have an access to it anymore. But I don’t want it public or protected either.

Comment: Are `Important` and `DependsOnImportant` both columns in the database table? I'm wondering because it would mean that having `false` for `Important` in the database will be an invalid state and always lead to an exception, no matter in what order the setters are called.

Comment: It is in the same table, but I don't see why would that always make an exception. It would make an exception only if DependsOnImportant is being set to true. Otherwise we have value=false, Important=false, value && !Important => false. Am I missing something?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I missed the `value &&` condition, my comment was nonsense. Well, as far as I can tell, you cannot control the order EF will set the properties in. At the moment I can only imagine to use a standard public automatic setter for `DependsOnImportant` and then fixup the (possibly) wrong state afterwards, either by calling a method manually after your queries or by calling it in the `ObjectMaterialized` event (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.objectmaterialized.aspx).

Comment: I know I could do that, but the problem is somewhere else. I know the database will be in consistent state (in my project), but I want to make sure anyone using my class cannot set values in wrong order. I got two solutions: first to create a wrapper class (exposed) that will deal with that logic and leave POCO class as simple as possible. But that means worse performance. Second, I can write to Microsoft to add new properties protection level: efonly :D At the moment I have this logic in UI-ish code which is not great, but will do. Thank you for your input, I leave this question open.